# Why does std::this_thread::get_id() function returns the same number in CentOS?

Tags: c++, stdthread

In the following code, the `.get_id()` call returns the same value when run on CentOS; but on Windows, the same code returns different values.

Why?

```cpp
#include <unistd.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

void dosomework()
{
    std::cout << std::this_thread::get_id() << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i){
        std::thread connectthread([](){
            dosomework();
        });
        std::cout << "connectthread:" << connectthread.get_id() << std::endl;
        connectthread.join(); 
        sleep(1000);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Since each thread is joined before starting the next one, the most obvious explanation is that ids of terminated threads are simply recycled.

Comment: do you mean the id's printed by the `dosomework` function and the `connectthread.get_id()` part are different?

Comment: @FantasticMrFox Well, in my Windows system, those two values are the same for each thread (as they should be). Just that they are different from one loop to the next.

Answer (score 3):

Because of the `connectthread.join();` call in your loop, each of your created threads will complete before another is started; thus, no two threads will be running at the same time.

Further, [as stated on cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/id) (bolding/emphasis mine)<sup>1</sup>; note that `get_id()` returns an object of `std::thread::id` class:

> Instances of this class may also hold the special distinct value that
> does not represent any thread. Once a thread has finished, the value
> of std::thread::id ***may*** be reused by another thread.

The word, "may," means that is up to the implementation/platform to decide whether or not to re-use an ID of a completed thread for a new one. Thus, both the Windows and CentOS operating systems are complying with the requirements for the IDs of the threads you/they create.

---

<sup>1</sup> The C++ Standard says much the same thing, though more obtusely. From [this Draft C++17 Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4713.pdf):

> ##### 33.3.2.1 Class thread::id       [thread.thread.id]
>
> …
> <sup>1</sup>    
> An object of type **`thread::id`** provides a unique identifier for each
> thread of execution and a single distinct value for all **`thread`** objects
> that do not represent a thread of execution (33.3.2). Each thread of
> execution has an associated **`thread::id`** object that is not equal to the
> **`thread::id`** object of any other thread of execution and that is not
> equal to the **`thread::id`** object of any thread object that does not
> represent threads of execution.

Comment: Note that if you add a line like `std::cout << "dead thread:" << connectthread.get_id() << std::endl;` **after** the `join()` call, you will (or *should*) get the same ('special') value each time. On Windows, this is `0` for thread objects that don't represent a running thread.